# Python Threading Exception & Socket Disconnect / WinError 10053

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, python-multithreading, fix-protocol

I'm trying to run a heartbeat message on a socket connection (every 30 seconds it sends a message), so I'm running it on it's own thread, and have tried it as daemon or not.  I'm on a virtual machine -- Windows x86.

The program runs correctly, and transmits the message, but on the 12th iteration of the heartbeat I begin getting 'Threading Error!' (and Socket disconnects) -- I've tried turning off firewalls, machine related stuff like that, but don't know what's going on with the connection/why it's dropping.  I've also tried this recursively, without threading -- I receive WinError 10053, established connection aborted by software in host machine.

```
def every(delay, task):
    next_time = time.time() + delay
    while True:
        time.sleep(max(0, next_time - time.time()))
        try:
            task()
        except Exception:
            print('Error threading!')
        next_time += (time.time() - next_time) // delay * delay + delay

def test():
    print("Threadtest", time.time())
```

class HB_Socket():

```
def __init__(self,IP='127.0.0.1',port=4000,hb = 30):
    self.IP = IP
    self.port = port
    self.HB = hb
    self.socket = socket() #AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM)
    self.connected = False

def cnct(self):
    s = self.socket
    #s.connect((self.IP,self.port))                                         #MOVED THIS 
    try:  
        s.connect((self.IP,self.port))
        print('Socket connected to {} on port {}'.format(self.IP,self.port))

        on = self.logOn()
        self.send(on)
        print('LogOn message sent')

        self.connected = True
        return 1
    except:
        print('Socket creation failed: {}')
        return 0


#Function being called in every()
def sendHB(self):
    hbsocket = self.socket
    print('PyHeartBeat client sending to IP {}'.format(self.IP,self.port))
    #while 1:
    hbsocket.sendto(HB_MSG,('127.0.0.1',self.port))
    if HB_SIM:
        sleep(self.HB)
        if datetime.datetime.now().time().hour >= 16:                      
            self.disconnect()
            return
        self.sendHB()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    HB = HB_Socket()
    HB.cnct()

    HB_SIM = False
    threading.Thread(target=every,args=(30,HB.sendHB)).start()

    HB_SIM = True                      #Recursive solution.
    #HB.sendHB()

    #Daemon / Recursive
    dmn = threading.Thread(target=HB.sendHB(), daemon=True)
    dmn.start()
```

Here's an image of the return with errors
[image: return in Spyder]

Comment: It’s impossible to test your code because you haven’t provided a [mre]. Please edit your code inthe question to provide a __minimal__ [mre] which I can paste into a file and __without adding anything__ run your code and see the problem you are seeing.

Comment: Added code to create a min reproducible example -- I thought it was reproducible, guess I forgot the cnct method.